# Linear fitting with GNU Scientific Library in C

Tags: c, linear-regression, gsl, data-fitting

I have two arrays of 64-bit integers (one for the x and one for the y values) I want to fit with a straight line starting from the origin. They both have length `num`.

I made a previous parsing of the two arrays so that they're both starting when they're zero, so I have to shift one of the two arrays, according to the value of `result`, either by `pos1` or by `pos2`.

Now, as I said, the arrays are 64-bit integer-sized, so I cast them as double. But whenever I call the following piece of code, the program crashes. `c1`, `cov11` and `sumsq` are defined outside as pointers to doubles.

```
if(result > 0)  
gsl_fit_mul((double *) array1 + pos2, 1,(double *) array2, 1, (num - pos2 - 1) * sizeof(uint64_t), c1, cov11, sumsq);
else
gsl_fit_mul((double *) array1, 1, (double *) array2 + pos1, 1, (num - pos2 - 1) * sizeof(uint64_t), c1, cov11, sumsq);
```

I tried reading [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Linear-regression-without-a-constant-term.html#Linear-regression-without-a-constant-term), but it's actully not so clear, and I think the problem is in the call to the arrays.

Thank you in advance.

---

EDIT: I changed approach. I wrote this function

```
void findFit(uint64_t *array1, uint64_t *array2, uint64_t num, double c1){
    double *array1_parallel = malloc(num * sizeof(double)), *array2_parallel = malloc(num * sizeof(double));

    for(uint64_t i = 0; i < num; i++){
        array1_parallel[i] = (double) array1[i];
        array2_parallel[i] = (double) array2[i];
    }

    double *cov11, *sumsq;

    gsl_fit_mul(array1_parallel, 1, array2_parallel, 1, num, &c1, cov11, sumsq);

    free(array2_parallel);
    free(array1_parallel);

    return;
}
```

passing to it the already shifted and parsed arrays, but it's still not working...

Comment: You cannot cast a whole array just by casting the pointer to it. You'll need to cast every element. So you'll need a parallel array of doubles, and fill them with the int values. One by one. In a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
If the integer arrays have dimension `num * sizeof(uint64_t)`, should I allocate `num * sizeof(double)` for the parallel array?

Comment: Yes, that is basically the idea. Same number of elements. (but sizes of elements *can* differ. (irrelevant) )

Comment: The caller probably expects its results back in *the same* arrays? In that case: you'll need to copy the array contents back to this int arrays. This may involve rounding tem.

Comment: Well, I actually just need the value of `c1`, these arrays are just temporary and will be freed afterwards.

Comment: I Just checked the link, the x,y arrays are not intended as IN+OUT paramaters, only input.

Comment: Yes, x and y are the experimental points which need to be fitted, what it does (I think, at least) is modify `c1`, `cov11` and `sumsq` in order to get the best fit.

Comment: Check the offsets you give it by adding pos. (just print pos and num before the function call)

Comment: I checked that when I changed approach (after the edit): the new arrays I pass to the function now are starting from the point I need and have a number of points lesser than the length of the total array, so they should be OK

Comment: (The posted code is wrong around line 6 - you're only setting array1_parallel, not array2_parallel)

Comment: Also, cov11 and sumsq look wrong to me.  I suspect those are out values, so you need to pass in the address of an actual value.  Should be something more like this:

    `double cov11, sumsq;`
    `gsl_fit_mul(array1_parallel, 1, array2_parallel, 1, num, &c1, &cov11, &sumsq);`

Comment: And, I'm not sure how you're calling findFit, but the value of c1 will not be meaningful after findFit returns.  Values are passed into C by value - if you want to modify a parameter, you pass in a pointer to it.  Which is what gsl_fit_mul is doing wihth cov11 and sumsq.

Comment: @MarkW yes, you're right about the setting the parallel arrays, I copy-pasted the wrong line, in the code it's correct (I'll edit it now).

So, to actually get the result of c1 what should I do? Would declaring the function as double and returning c1, without passing it as argument, be useful?

Comment: @Enzo yes, making c1 your return value would be good C style.  Returning values by passing pointers in the parameters is typically only used if there is more than one return value (which is why gsl_fit_mul returns c1, cov11 and sumsq that way).

Answer (score 0):

Casting in C can be confusing.  You're not casting the individual values, you're casting the pointer to those values.  Which isn't what you want.

So, you're telling gsl_fit_mul() - "here's an array of doubles, not the array of ints that the compiler thinks it is."  But they really *are* ints, so that's not going to work.

You need to create a second array of doubles and cast each of the ints to convert your ints into doubles.

so:

```
double* double_array1, *double_array2;
size_t i;

double_array1 = malloc(sizeof(double)*num);
double_array2 = malloc(sizeof(double)*num);
for (i=0; i < num; ++i) {
    double_array1[i] = array1[i];
    double_array2[i] = array2[i];
}


...
gsl_fit_mul(double_array1 + ..., double_array2, ...)
...
free(double_array1);
free(double_array2);
```

(Be sure to call free() on those arrays after you're done.  If you know a maximum value for num at compile time, those arrays can be declared statically and you don't need to malloc/free them).

Also, I don't know this library at all, but I doubt that the 'n' parameter should be the size in bytes of the input arrays (which is what you're getting when you multiply by sizeof(uint64_t)).  Just pass in the number of elements (num - minus your offsetting magic).

Comment: I edited the original post. It's still not working, unfortunately.